# How do you deploy a BLANK copy of your SQL 2005 express database with your ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2005, deployment

Age old question! When you have finished developing and testing your ASP.Net web application, the database you want to deploy is now full of test information and needs to be emptied (and identity fields reseeded to 1) before you deploy.

When using a server instance, this isnt difficult (create a SQL script to do the job) but when using a user instance, its seems there is no easy way around?

Can anyone help with this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this could help you http://rip747.wordpress.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-import-export-reset-identity-keys-no-workaround-2005-sucks-period-the-end/

Here is another good one
http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/mosessaur/archive/2007/12/09/sql-server-2005-clean-your-database-records-amp-reset-identity-columns-all-in-6-lines.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can connect SSMS to a user instance DB, it just requires [a bit of voodoo](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2006/11/22/connecting-to-sql-express-user-instances-in-management-studio.aspx) to discover the DB name.

As for scripting the sql, you can also use the [Sql Server hosting toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/sqlhost) to do this.